# Remove single array from a 2D array based on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have this array
`const args = [[ 64, 120 ],[ 65, 100 ],[ 70, 150 ],[ 56, 90 ],[ 75, 190 ],[ 60, 95 ],[ 68, 110 ]]`

I have written the below code

```
function sortNums(a, b) {
    if (a[0] !== b[0]) {
        return a[0] - b[0];
    } else {
        return b[1] - a[1];
    }
}


function longestPossible(nums) {

    let res = nums.map(x => +x);

    let val = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i += 2) {
        val.push([res[i], res[i + 1]]);
    }

    val.sort(sortNums);

    let finalRes = [];
    for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
        finalRes.splice(val[i][1], 0, val[i]);
    }
}
```

I want to sort the above array such that it becomes;

`[[ 56, 90 ],[ 60, 95 ],[ 65, 100 ],[68, 110 ],[ 70, 150 ],[ 75, 190 ]]` but I currently have  `[[ 56, 90 ],[ 60, 95 ],[ 64, 120 ],[ 65, 100 ],[68, 110 ],[ 70, 150 ],[ 75, 190 ]]`

**The condition for sorting is that `56, 60, 65` are in ascending order while 120 is in between 95 and 100 causing disruption in the order `90, 95, 120, 100` from what I currently have**

How do I remove the array `[ 64, 120 ]` after sorting?

Comment: What is the condition for removing an element? Why should `[64, 120]` be removed?

Comment: The condition seems to be that both "sides" of the array are ordered ascendingly, and if it is impossible for an element to fit said pattern it is removed.

Comment: @iota I have updated the question as I initially forgot to add that.Please let me know if it's better now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
let args = [[ 64, 120 ],[ 65, 100 ],[ 70, 150 ],[ 56, 90 ],[ 75, 190 ],[ 60, 95 ],[ 68, 110 ]];
args = args.sort((a,b)=>a[0] != b[0] ? a[0] - b[0] : b[1] - a[1])
  .filter((x, i)=>i === args.length - 1 || x[1] <= args[i+1][1]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(args));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @iota. One question though, why JSON.stringify the array when logging the array without JSON.stringify still works?

Comment: No problem. Using `JSON.stringify` displays more compactly in Stack Snippets. It's not an important detail.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what's going on in the code? I thought I would get it...

Comment: @camelCase After sorting, we use `filter` to find which items to keep. We only keep items whose second element is less than or equal to the second element of the next item in the sorted array. We also need to add a condition to keep the last item since there is not an item after it.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate and find/remove the unwanted item/s.

```js
const
    args = [[64, 120], [65, 100], [70, 150], [56, 90], [75, 190], [60, 95], [68, 110]];

args.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0] || b[1] - a[1]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(args));

let i = 0;
while (i < args.length - 1) {
    if (args[i][1] > args[i + 1][1]) {
        args.splice(i, 1);
        continue;
    }
    i++;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(args));
```

Comment: Thanks @Nina Scholz. Always to the rescue